# Limit as n approaches infinity of (log(n!) / nlog(n))

Tags: calculus, limits

I'm stumped with a limit. I know the answer (because I looked on wolframalpha) but I really want to know how to reach the correct answer. If you have any hints or tips on getting there I'd be most appreciative!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint:**

> $$ \ln(n!) = \sum_{k=1}^{n} \ln k \sim \int_{1}^{n} \ln x dx =n\ln n-n+1 .$$